How to take memory snapshot of extension host in Remote-SSH?

I am working on a VSCode extension
There's a bug where memory usage grows quickly under certain conditions, but this only happens while running the extension in remote-ssh, where the extension is running on the SSH host.
How do I do the equivalent of code --inspect-extensions 9299 for the extension host that's installed on the remote server?

